# Powershell script to fetch task name from notepad and find the status of it in windows task scheduler

Tags: powershell

I need a PowerShell script where the tasks listed out in a text file needs to be read and the status of those tasks needs to be fetched from the windows task scheduler and output in to a csv file.

I am able to read the contents using `Get-Content` cmdlet.But `Get-ScheduledTask` is throwing an error that it is not recognized as a valid cmdlet.

Kindly help me with this as I am new to PowerShell.

Get-ScheduledTask tasks | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Select-Object TaskName, LastTaskResult | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\First\one.csv

I have a txt file named tasks which contain the list of tasks to be iterated and listed out to a csv file

Comment: Kindly share your script with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
$tasks = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Tasks.txt"
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $tasks | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Select-Object TaskName, LastTaskResult | Export-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Tasks.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Txt file is in following format:

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
```

I've tried it in PS 4 on Windows 8.1, you don't have this cmdlet in previous versions of Windows (like Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2).

For those previous versions, you can use this [great module](https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover-PowerShell/tree/master/modules/TaskScheduler). You should extract the entire folder in your `Modules` folder, e,g. to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` and then you can use `Get-ScheduledTask` from module like this:

```
Import-Module TaskScheduler
Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Tasks.txt" | ForEach-Object { Get-ScheduledTask -Name $_ | Select-Object Name,LastRunTime } | Export-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Tasks.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Other solution would be to try to play around with `schtasks.exe` or the `Schedule.Service COM object` but I think the module `TaskScheduler` is easier for you.

Comment: Hi Petar, Thanks for the reply.Mine is a windows 7 machine. The command Get-Scheduled Task is throwing an error. Any other way for running this code in windows 7?

Comment: Mila, I've edited my answer with another solution that works in Windows 7. Please check it out, and approve it if it works for you.